# openssl_decrypt PHP to Crypto Node js

Tags: node.js, cryptojs

I have a problem with crypto in nodejs, from PHP I have encrypted text and I would like to decrypt it from node js, but I get an error when trying to decrypt the text:

> `wrong final block length` .

Attached code of encryption in php 7.0.

```
public static function encrypt($string) {

        if($string == "" || $string == NULL){
            return "";
        }
        return openssl_encrypt($string, 'AES-128-ECB',  'mypasswordinstrig');

    }
```

Node v16.15  decryption code (In this function I have problems)

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const CRYPT_ALGORITHM = 'aes-128-ecb';

module.exports.decrypt = (dataEncoded) => {
  const key = crypto.scryptSync('mypasswordinstrig', '', 16);
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(CRYPT_ALGORITHM, key, null);
  let decrypted = decipher.update(dataEncoded);

  decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final('hex')]);
  
  return decrypted.toString();
};
```